# How to find information in a file using regular expressions on Linux

Tags: regex, linux, shell, scripting

I have a file with many lines in it. One of them look like :

```
set auto_upgrade {1 2 3 4}
```

The list can contain more numbers.

Now, in a shell script I want to look into this file and find out what is the last number in the list. In the example above, it should find 4. I have a regular expression to find this :

```
set auto_upgrade {\([0-9] \)*\([0-9]\{1,\}\)}
```

The second group contains what I need. 
However, how do I use this regular expression ? I tried *sed* but it returns the full file with a substition. I just want the second group.

Thanks in advance, 
Barth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, start sed in quiet mode: it should not print anything unless told to do so (that's the flag `-n`). Then print only if a substitution has been made (that's the pattern modifier `p`)

```
sed -n 's/set auto_upgrade {\([0-9] \)*\([0-9]\{1,\}\)}/\2/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

cat filename | perl -pe 's/^.* (\d+)\}/$1/'

should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*\([0-9]\+\)}/\1/g'
```

The "\1" in the replacement section matches the group. i.e. (ignoring the escapes and quotes)

```
sed s/pattern1(pattern2)/\1/g
```

will return the matched part of pattern2